# Google maps Geolocation not asking for permission

Tags: php, html, api, google-api, google-geolocation

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API in the following page: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

and all I'm doing is copying the code on that page and pasting it on a testing page on my site.
http://kwt-events-com.stackstaging.com/content/api/maps.php

I do have an API key. I used it and the page loads great with google map.

**The problem is** that it cannot detect the location showing this error:
"Error: The Geolocation service failed"

**What I've tried:**
is to allow location detection in the browser and the computer.
I tried different browsers on the same machine "macos".
I tried on another machine "another pc and another mac".
I tried on the phone "ios".

same Error

i know i cant post all the code but ill do so you guys can help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geolocation</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script>
  // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
  // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
  // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
  // locate you.
  var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=IHAD-MY-API-KEY-HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Pfffftt, as though Google needed to ask for permission...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your page is being served over HTTP not HTTPS, and geolocation is only available if the page is served securely since Chrome 50, Safari 10, and Firefox 55.

Answer (score 1):

First, Your page should be https. Google geo location will only work in https.

You can use this simple code too

```
    function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     } else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
     }
   }
 getLocation();

   function showPosition(position) { 
   var latitude = position.coords.latitude; 
   var longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
   console.log(latitude,longitude);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was helpful, I don’t know about the ssl “https” thing until now